# Start uwp app, pipe output to file

Tags: uwp

I want to start an console UWP app from command line and pipe its console output to a file. Is this possible? Like this (doesnt work):

explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\MyFreshUWPApp!App > log.txt

Comment: I solved this by creating an alias for the app so I could run it straight from the command line

Comment: If you have solved this, please feel free post your answer below and accept it.